# Trouble with Cypress Upload files, name repetition

Tags: variables, upload, constants, cypress

I'm relatively new into Cypress (Java S) so I've created a some code to check on an upload feature of a particular system. Work just fine, the issue I'm facing now is, due the scanning process the system has, when a file with an used name is re-uploaded will give an error (rightfully doing so). My question, having the following code, what is the best approach to add a "name generator" for the files?.

```
cy.log('File Upload');
    const validfile = ('pic.jpg');
    cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile(validfile);
    cy.get('webmarker').click();
```

Thanks in advance.
Ps: using cypress-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can use some random number generator and add in your code. So it will not be same e.g.

```
const uuid = () => Cypress._.random(0, 1e6)
const id = uuid()
const validfile = (`pic.jpg${id}`)
cy.log('File Upload')
cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile(validfile)
cy.get('webmarker').click()
```

Or create a custom command for that purpose and use it